# AnonymousParty is revealed when verifying tx dependency chain?

Tags: identity, corda

Quoting Corda's doc: 
"Using AnonymousParty to identify parties in states and commands prevents nodes from learning the identities of the parties involved in a transaction when they verify the transaction’s dependency chain."

I still do not quite understand how identities can be kept concealed when verification of dependent transaction happens. I have an example that highlights this:

Assume that Tx01, Tx02, and Tx03 happens sequentially.

- Tx01: CashTokeniser issues 10€ to Alice. No identity is concealed.
- Tx02: Alice sends 10€ to Bob. Here, both agree to conceal their identity using SwapIdentityFlow. Let's say Alice's new pubKey is "Xavier", and Bob's is "Yankee".
- Tx03: Bob sends 10€ to Chloe. No identity is concealed.

My current sequence of understanding is as follows:

1. By the time Chloe verifies Tx03, as part of resolving tx dependency chain, she receives Tx01 and Tx02 from Bob.
2. Chloe is definitely aware that it is Bob who sends the Tx03. So, Bob does not benefit from concealing his identity to Chloe. Chloe knows that despite "Yankee" in the InputState, it is actually Bob.
3. When inspecting Tx02, Chloe sees that the InputState belongs to "Xavier".
4. When inspecting Tx01, Chloe sees that the OutputState belongs to "Alice". Since the InputState of Tx02 points to the OutputState of Tx01, Chloe can deduce that "Xavier" is actually Alice.

My naive conclusion: party's true identity can be deduced by inspecting the transaction chain in the verification process.

I am sure that I understand the concept in a wrong manner. Can someone please shed a light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudonymous public keys are not the perfect privacy solution, as shown by other blockchain platforms. This is why Corda also implements other mechanisms such as need-to-know data distribution.

However, they do still provide some protection. For example:

1. If in TX01, the cash is initially issued to one of Alice's pseudonymous public keys, Chloe would not be able to identify Alice's role in the chain
2. If Chloe transfers the cash to Demi in TX04, Demi will not be able to deduce Bob's participation